# CSS: Removing extra space when 2 divs are within a link in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have two divs within a link in the following form:

```
<a href="#" id="wrapper>
    <div class="div1"></div>
    <div class="div2">Text</div>
</a>
```

CSS and HTML link:
(http://jsfiddle.net/gfjnosvg/)

In short, "div1" is used for the background image of the link, whereas "div2" is some text within the link... If you run this in JSFiddle (Link above), you can see that there is a small unwanted margin on the left.. 
(In Chrome browser!!)

Can anyone tell me how to remove this space??
(I am keeping two divs inside the link for a particular reason, so any solution that requires changing the structure or simply setting "background-image" for the entire link won't work for me)

In other words, I want to keep "div1" as it is.

Thanks!

Comment: [Something like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/gfjnosvg/3/)

Comment: Not sure what unwanted margin you are referring to. I am using the latest Chrome version and don't really see any such thing. Could you maybe add some screen-shot and point out? Are you by any chance referring to the blue area? If yes, that is the first `div`.

Answer (score 1):

One user earlier had posted this here, but he deleted his answer.

Use `display:-webkit-table-cell;`

```css
#wrapper {
    display: inline-table;
    background-color: red;
    
    width: 20vw;
    height: 20vw;  
}

.div1 {
    display: -webkit-table-cell;
    
    background-image: url("http://doc.jsfiddle.net/_downloads/jsfiddle-desktop-1440x900-a.png");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;   
}

.div2 {
  display: -webkit-table-cell;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="wrapper">
    <div class="div1"></div>
    <div class="div2">Text</div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Div 1 is showing as a margin, as it actually have no width to display as a block element.
Try adding a width to Div 1 so that it will show up.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By default most browsers add some margin around the outside of the  but you can set body to have margin: 0 and padding: 0 to counteract this, I added this code to your JSFiddle to remove spacing:

```
body {
margin: 0;
}
```

I'd even go so far as to say you really need to use a browser reset like this: http://nicolasgallagher.com/about-normalize-css/